# Can a Transformer heal naturally / repair itself?

Tags: transformers

Throughout the movies each Transformer gets banged up quite regularly, and generally a few scenes later they seem to be fine again.

Assuming [Ratchet](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Ratchet_(Movie)) isn't around, I'm wondering does a Transformer's body repair itself subconsciously or does each Transformer sit down and manually repair itself or initiate some repair protocol?

Is this issue ever addressed in any canon? I don't think it's covered in the movies, and I can't remember the cartoons.

Comment: In the live-action movies, Ratchet specifically mentions that he has been working to repair Bumblebee. It's not spelled out in the movies, but the rest of the materials explain that it's been quite some time since Bumblebee was damaged. Megatron is heavily damaged in Transformers 2, and still shows the largely un-repaired battle damage in TF 3.

Comment: @phantom42 yeah so that would indicate that they don't heal at all. With the amount of bits and pieces that come off each Transformer during every battle, Ratchet definitely has his work cut out for him.